# c++ - string of 64 ASCII characters overflows malloc(64 * sizeof(char))

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, console-application

The below code throws an error if I provide a string that is 64 characters long of hexadecimals *(ie: 26C8D8AB82B027808A371BC46EA789364AB8419F2B17EADFE955CBE5C6369011)*, even though I allocated 64 * sizeof(char) bytes for it which should be enough:

```
char* username = (char*)malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
std::cin >> username;
free(username);
```

The error is thrown in the third line when I free the allocated memory:

> CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap
>   buffer.

This does not happen with 63 characters or less. Can anyone tell me why exactly 64 * sizeof(char) is not enough and why is the error thrown when freeing the memory not before ...

Comment: @TimStraubinger std::malloc certainly is C++... But you are right it should not be used without a good reason (such as needing to pass the allocation ownership to C code).

Comment: @TimStraubinger it's the same thing, new[] and free() give the same result. Delete however does not throw the error. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: @TimStraubinger ...what? `new` and `delete` should not be recommended for general use either, when  the stdlib provides so many safe classes that handle dynamic allocation so users don't have to. Nor is dynamic allocation required for polymorphism, which is what I assume you're trying to say with "oop-style objects" (a tautology if ever I heard one); only a pointer or reference is required, and the target can be on the stack. If you're going to recommend things to a clearly new user, recommend good things.

Comment: @underscore_d: I think Tim was drawing a distinction between POD (plain old data) where `malloc()` and `free()` can be safely used, vs "objects" with non-trivial construction, where `malloc()` gives a result that isn't yet a valid object.  Polymorphism isn't part of the picture there.

Comment: @MikeMouawad: You don't know just HOW accurate that statement about throwing errors is. This is primarily the difference in C++ code between `malloc` and `new` (aside from calling the ctor / dtor for non plain-old-data types). One will throw an exception if it fails.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman yeah delete just doesn't seem to care

Comment: That actually wasn't what I meant ;) The reason `delete` doesn't care is because you used it wrong. Replace it with `delete []` to free your array of `char`'s and it should produce the same results.

Comment: Off topic, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition. Multiplying it is redundant.

Comment: @MarkRansom yeah but why not :P

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman if `delete [] username` deletes the array does `delete username` only delete the pointer or what?

edit: I think I see what you mean, comparing new[] and malloc regarding the overflow, because malloc allocates from the heap (the error is thrown because of the heap overflow), while new allocates from free store

Comment: `new` can allocate from anywhere it wants actually, it's an overloadable operator. `malloc (...)` is guaranteed not to throw an exception in C++ though. Exception unwinding complicates the `new` operator, which can potentially be implemented by wrapping `malloc (...)`. The difference between `delete` and `delete [...]` would be that `delete [...]` calls the destructor for each element of the array. It's undefined behavior to allocate an array with `new [...]` and then free it using `delete`.

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh254939.aspx) for more details. If `new` fails, it can throw an exception and cause a lot of code to unwind. `malloc` failure will generally just return `nullptr` and keep going.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C strings are NULL-terminated.

You did not leave space for the terminator.

The error is detected when freeing the memory, because that's the function that looked at the padding after the object and found it was corrupted.  If you disable memory debugging, there might not be any checking (possibly even no padding) and this sort of error could go undetected until it trashes a completely unrelated piece of data.

If you know the exact length already and don't need a terminator to mark the end, you can use

```
cin.read(username, 64);
```

This will not store a terminator, and also won't ever read more (or less) than 64 characters of input, so it will not overflow.

Comment: `std::cin >> username` inserts a null terminator, but since the original buffer was not being allocated large enough to hold the null terminator, a buffer overflow occurred after 64 input characters were read. You can use `std::setw()` to avoid the buffer overflow: `char* username = new char[65]; std::cin >> std::setw(65) >> username; ...` Of course, it would be safer to use `std::string` instead of `char[]`: `std::string username; std::cin >> username;`, then use `username.c_str()` when needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: As long as you acknowledge that the returned C-string is only valid while the original `std::string` is in scope. This is very different behavior than allocating and later freeing a `char` array. It's arguably less safe.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I learned to never use c_str unless it's necessary, because the array will be destroyed when the string goes out of scope, like when passing it from a function to a calling function it just gets destroyed.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: That depends on the coding. `std::string username` could easily be allocated at the same time that `char *username` was being allocated, and stay in scope until the same time that `free(username)` was being called.

Comment: @MikeMouawad: that is only true if you hold on to the `char*` pointer returned by `c_str()` after the `std::string` has been destroyed. You shouldn't be doing that anyway. Call `c_str()` at the time you need the `char*`, when the `std::string` is still in scope.

Answer (score 1):

A C-style string must contain one more `char` than the number of characters you try to put into it, to leave room for the terminating null character.

Answer (score 1):

you are neglecting NUL CHAR (`'\0'`) at the end of the string...

you should allocate 65 byte for a string with max length of 64

Comment: The name of the ASCII character is NUL, not NULL (which is C define for null pointer). Just saying this, because using NULL in actual code for end-of-string is unfortunately common (and wrong).

Comment: Yeah, the character is `'\0'`. ...but of course, if writing a `"string literal"`, this is automatically appended, so including it `"like this\0"` would be pointless and wasteful. Rather, it's for use in other situations, e.g. to check for the end while looping over a null-terminated buffer.

Comment: @hyde thanks for the nuance, edited to reflect both NUL and '\0'.

Comment: @hyde in C++, `0`, `'\0'`, and `NULL` are all integer constants with the same value. You can use whichever makes the most sense for the context you're in. I'd agree that `NULL` doesn't make much sense in a character context, but that doesn't make it wrong. When I speak of null terminating characters I never capitalize it, hopefully people pick up on the subtle distinction.

Comment: @Mark: But in C, `NULL` is `((void*)0)` which doesn't implicitly convert to `char`, and in C++ `NULL` is likely to change to `nullptr` at some point.  True, that would not be backward compatible, but it would not be a "breaking" change, because it would only change the behavior of code that's already broken.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was surprised when I learned that C++ `NULL` didn't have the `void*` cast. I wonder why that is?

Comment: @Mark because no implicit downcast makes `int* p = (void*)0;` a compile error.